# DHL Shipment request getting 500 not found error

Tags: c#, xml, web-services, soap, dhl

i have created shipment request to dhl for shipment label in form of image/pdf,but i am getting 500 not found error,but when i do rate request it works, following is my code
i have added soap security header then also getting unauthorized request gone through dhl api documentation but didn't get any answer

```
            public class SoapSecurityHeader : MessageHeader
            {
                private readonly string _password, _username, _nonce;
                private readonly DateTime _createdDate;

                public SoapSecurityHeader(string id, string username, string password, string nonce)
                {
                    _password = password;
                    _username = username;
                    _nonce = nonce;
                    _createdDate = DateTime.Now;
                    this.Id = id;
                }

                public string Id { get; set; }

                public override string Name
                {
                    get { return "Security"; }
                }

                public override string Namespace
                {
                    get { return "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd"; }
                }

                protected override void OnWriteStartHeader(XmlDictionaryWriter writer, MessageVersion messageVersion)
                {
                    writer.WriteStartElement("wsse", Name, Namespace);
                    writer.WriteXmlnsAttribute("wsse", Namespace);
                }

                protected override void OnWriteHeaderContents(XmlDictionaryWriter writer, MessageVersion messageVersion)
                {
                    writer.WriteStartElement("wsse", "UsernameToken", Namespace);
                    writer.WriteAttributeString("Id", "UsernameToken-10");
                    writer.WriteAttributeString("wsu", "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd");

                    writer.WriteStartElement("wsse", "Username", Namespace);
                    writer.WriteValue(_username);
                    writer.WriteEndElement();

                    writer.WriteStartElement("wsse", "Password", Namespace);
                    writer.WriteAttributeString("Type", "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText");
                    writer.WriteValue(_password);
                    writer.WriteEndElement();

                    writer.WriteStartElement("wsse", "Nonce", Namespace);
                    writer.WriteAttributeString("EncodingType", "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary");
                    writer.WriteValue(_nonce);
                    writer.WriteEndElement();

                    writer.WriteStartElement("wsse", "Created", Namespace);
                    writer.WriteValue(_createdDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss"));
                    writer.WriteEndElement();

                    writer.WriteEndElement();
                }
            }
            public static string Base64Encode(string plainText)
            {
                var plainTextBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(plainText);
                return System.Convert.ToBase64String(plainTextBytes);
            }
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                string usn = "XXXXXX";
                string pwd = "XXXXXX";
 SoapSecurityHeader soapSecurityHeader = new SoapSecurityHeader(Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), usn , pwd , Base64Encode(Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N")));
                    string xmlBody = @"<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
                                                <soapenv:Envelope 
                                                    xmlns:soapenv='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/' 
                                                    xmlns:glob='http://scxgxtt.phx-dc.dhl.com/glDHLExpressLabel/providers/globalLabel'>";
            xmlBody += soapSecurityHeader.ToString();
              xmlBody += @"            <soap:Body> " +
                                                    "<shipreq:ShipmentRequest>" +
                                                        "<RequestedShipment>" +
                                                            "<ShipmentInfo>" +
                                                                "<DropOffType>REQUEST_COURIER</DropOffType>                                                          <!--Mandatory-->" +
                                                                "<ServiceType>U</ServiceType>                                                                                             <!--Mandatory-->" +
                                                                "<Account> XXXXXXXXX</Account>                                                                                      <!--Mandatory-->" +
                                                                "<Currency>EUR</Currency>                                                                                                  <!--Mandatory-->" +
                                                                "<UnitOfMeasurement>SI</UnitOfMeasurement>                                                            <!--Mandatory-->" +
                                                                "<PackagesCount>1</PackagesCount>                                                                                <!--Optional-->" +
                                                                "<LabelType>PDF</LabelType>                                                                                               <!--Optional-->" +
                                                                "<LabelTemplate>ECOM26_84_001</LabelTemplate>                                                      <!--Optional-->" +
                                                            "</ShipmentInfo>" +
                                                            "<ShipTimestamp>2010-10-29T09:30:47GMT+01:00</ShipTimestamp>                         <!--Mandatory-->" +
                                                            "<PickupLocationCloseTime>16:12</PickupLocationCloseTime>                                       <!--Optional-->" +
                                                            "<SpecialPickupInstruction>fragile items</SpecialPickupInstruction>                             <!--Optional-->" +
                                                            "<PickupLocation>west wing 3rd Floor</PickupLocation>                                                     <!--Optional-->" +
                                                            "<PaymentInfo>DDP</PaymentInfo>                                                                                            <!--Mandatory-->" +
                                                            "<InternationalDetail>" +
                                                                "<Commodities>" +
                                                                    "<NumberOfPieces>1</NumberOfPieces>                                                                      <!--Mandatory-->" +
                                                                    "<Description>ppps sd</Description>                                                                            <!--Mandatory-->" +
                                                                    "<CountryOfManufacture>CZ</CountryOfManufacture>                                               <!--Optional-->" +
                                                                    "<Quantity>1</Quantity>                                                                                                        <!--Optional-->" +
                                                                    "<UnitPrice>10</UnitPrice>                                                                                                     <!--Optional-->" +
                                                                    "<CustomsValue>1</CustomsValue>                                                                                  <!--Optional-->" +
                                                                "</Commodities>" +
                                                                "<Content>NON_DOCUMENTS</Content>                                                                             <!--Mandatory-->" +
                                                            "</InternationalDetail>" +
                                                            "<Ship>" +
                                                                "<Shipper>" +
                                                                    "<Contact>" +
                                                                        "<PersonName>John Smith</PersonName>                                                               <!--Mandatory-->" +
                                                                        "<CompanyName>DHL</CompanyName>                                                                  <!--Mandatory-->" +
                                                                        "<PhoneNumber>003932423423</PhoneNumber>                                                 <!--Mandatory-->" +
                                                                        "<EmailAddress>John.Smith@dhl.com</EmailAddress>                                         <!--Optional-->" +
                                                                    "</Contact>" +
                                                                    "<Address>" +
                                                                        "<StreetLines>V Parku 2308/10</StreetLines>                                                           <!--Mandatory-->" +
                                                                        "<City>Prague</City>                                                                                                     <!--Mandatory-->" +
                                                                        "<PostalCode>14800</PostalCode>                                                                           <!--Mandatory-->" +
                                                                        "<CountryCode>CZ</CountryCode>                                                                              <!--Mandatory-->" +
                                                                    "</Address>" +
                                                                "</Shipper>" +
                                                                "<Recipient>" +
                                                                    "<Contact>" +
                                                                        "<PersonName>Jane Smith</PersonName>                                                                 <!--Mandatory-->" +
                                                                        "<CompanyName>Deutsche Post DHL</CompanyName>                                        <!--Mandatory-->" +
                                                                        "<PhoneNumber>004922832432423</PhoneNumber>                                          <!--Mandatory-->" +
                                                                        "<EmailAddress>Jane.Smith@dhl.de</EmailAddress>                                               <!--Optional-->" +
                                                                    "</Contact>" +
                                                                    "<Address>" +
                                                                        "<StreetLines>Via Felice Matteucci 2</StreetLines>                                                      <!--Mandatory-->" +
                                                                        "<City>Firenze</City>                                                                                                               <!--Mandatory-->" +
                                                                        "<PostalCode>50127</PostalCode>                                                                                     <!--Mandatory-->" +
                                                                        "<CountryCode>IT</CountryCode>                                                                                          <!--Mandatory-->" +
                                                                    "</Address>" +
                                                                "</Recipient>" +
                                                            "</Ship>" +
                                                            "<Packages>" +
                                                                "<RequestedPackages number='1'>                                                                                                   <!--Mandatory-->" +
                                                                    "<InsuredValue>10</InsuredValue>                                                                                               <!--Optional-->" +
                                                                    "<Weight>9.0</Weight>                                                                                                                    <!--Mandatory-->" +
                                                                    "<Dimensions>" +
                                                                        "<Length>46</Length>                                                                                                                 <!--Mandatory-->" +
                                                                        "<Width>34</Width>                                                                                                               <!--Mandatory-->" +
                                                                        "<Height>31</Height>                                                                                                               <!--Mandatory-->" +
                                                                    "</Dimensions>" +
                                                                    "<CustomerReferences>TEST CZ-IT</CustomerReferences>                                                   <!--Mandatory-->" +
                                                                "</RequestedPackages>" +
                                                            "</Packages>" +
                                                        "</RequestedShipment>" +
                                                    "</shipreq:ShipmentRequest>" +
                                                "</soap:Body>" +
                                            "</soap:Envelope>";
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://wsbexpress.dhl.com/sndpt/expressRateBook");
        byte[] bytes;
        bytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(xmlBody);
        request.ContentType = "text/xml; encoding='utf-8'";
        request.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
        request.Method = "POST";
        Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
        requestStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        requestStream.Close();
        HttpWebResponse response;
        response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
            string responseStr = new StreamReader(responseStream).ReadToEnd();
            //return responseStr;
        }
    }
```

am i doing any wrong in code?

Comment: Your xml is not valid.  Put a break point online beginning with "HttpWebRequestrequest".  Then hover over variable  xmlBody and click on down arrow and select "Text Visualizer".  Copy entire text.  Then from menu : Project : Add New Item : Xml File.  Paste code into window.  Error will show up in 
Error View like any compiler error.  You are missing namespaces 'soap', 'shipreq' and a lot more issues.